# Open link in new tab using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div and some links within it.
I want to open these links in new tabs so am using the following code:

```
$(".classname").find("a").target = "_blank";
```

However it is not working.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it wrong you can use [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), try this:-

```
$(".classname").find("a").attr('target',"_blank");
```

Comment: this is working fine for me... the only issue is that pdf links are opening in different window instead of another tab

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `.attr()` API of jQuery. [Check .attr() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

You can apply attribute using

```
$(el).attr('attrname', 'attrValue');
```